# Can i get project setting value from hex output file in IAR workbench?

Tags: arm, embedded, hex, iar, hex-file

I'm beginner in IAR workbench and any part of embedded s/w.
I suddenly had to compile hex code for controller product.
so that reason, I succeeded in uploading an existing hex file (no error at all.) to the product using the flash loader and i check all the functions working well.
But when i uploaded the hex file that i changed some values for testing in the original file
(cuz, i have to change some values for customer's demanding later),
I can upload but it doesn't work at all.. I think debugging or other value was missing.

In this situation, is there a way to get debugging values ​​or other linker values ​​set in the existing hexa file?
Because the predecessor didn't left any information about setting value, so it's hard to ask original setting value.

I use ewarm, IAR 8.5ver
(no license ver. so i just can use this program for 30days because I failed so many times past IAR versions)

If you have any suggestions or set debugging / linker value please let me know
(I changed configuration file, output in linker)
Thanks for reading this!

Comment: Hex files commonly don't include any information that is unnecessary on the machine level. Without sources or at least a map file, you will have a hard time to find the right places in the binary.

Comment: @thebusybee Thanks for reply. I have the original source, but I don't think I can get any debugging or other values. Anyway, I am going to find another file for the config values.